# configuration setup for remote database server access in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have web server(10.1.1.3) and database server(10.1.1.5)
I am trying to change configuration.php in web server

I changed

```
    public host="10.1.1.5:3306"
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = 'xxxxxx';
    public $db = 'jomsocial';
```

As a result, it gives me this error.

Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.

I believe that that is some problem with remote access.
Any solution for that?
Thank you.

Comment: try changing the host to "localhost"

Comment: @Lodder the OP's trying to connect to a "remote database" so setting the host to "localhost" won't be any help. draford have you configured remote access on your database server?

Answer (score 0):

```
public host="localhost"
public $user = 'root';
public $password = 'root';
public $db = 'jomsocial';
```

Use this variables.

If it is not working please use control panel username and password. It will work.